# Removing ShareActionProvider white border

Tags: android, layout, shareactionprovider

The ShareActionProvider always got an **white border** surrounding it.

[image]

I'm using the support version applied on a Toolbar.

**ShareActionProvider**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

it is the background of `activityChooserView`
this is how I have fixed this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/SVToolbar.Green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/SVPopupListStyle</item>
    <item name="activityChooserViewStyle">@style/ActionBar.ActivityChooser</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/SVActionMenuTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.ActivityChooser" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following command to do it:

```
mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(null)
```

Hope it can help you
[if model = null, icon won't be shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjYQi.png)

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.

Comment: Better to paste the code in rather just a screenshot.